# Java runtime.exec process hangs

Tags: java, ffmpeg, runtime.exec

So basically my program creates a process of ffplay(program based on ffmpeg that plays audio and video), but it hangs(have to force kill the program, loading wheel of death, etc.) about 15 seconds into playing.  What is also interesting is that I call it with -autoexit which should kill the program at the end of the audio or video, but it doesn't close.

```
import java.lang.Runtime;
import java.lang.Process;
import java.io.IOException;
public class FFPlay
{
    Process proc;
    public FFPlay(String fileToPlay, String fileName) 
    {
        try
        {
            String[] command = {"/Users/myusername/Documents/Java Projects/SwingTest/ffplay", "-window_title", fileName, "-x", "500", "-y", "500", "-autoexit", fileToPlay};
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); 
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?  Is this a bad method for executing binaries?  I don't know much about the Runtime and Process classes to begin with.

Edit: Method that calls the above class

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    if (e.getClickCount() == 2)
    {
        int index = songList.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
        FFPlay player = new FFPlay(songList.getModel().getElementAt(index).toString(),songList.getModel().getElementAt(index).getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe more detailed what you are doing - I got confused from  your description. The posted code is incomplete. How do you call it and what happens (step  step2 step3 ...)

Comment: @PaulEdison I can post the rest of the code if you like, but they are just user interfaces.   I have a JScrollPane that contains a JList of songs(all the songs in the JList are File objects).  There is a MouseListener on the JList so that when a song is double clicked it creates a new FFPlay Object and feeds it the FIle object in string form.  I posted the the method that calls it in an edit of the original post.

Comment: Most likely, the process cannot write to its standard output.  Runtime.exec is obsolete.  Try starting the process with `new ProcessBuilder(command).inheritIO().start()` instead.  Or did you mean that your program, not ffplay, is hanging?  If that’s the case, it’s because you’re holding up the event dispatch thread in your mouseClicked method.  Starting your process in a new thread will resolve that.

Comment: 1) *"my program creates a process of ffplay(program based on ffmpeg that plays audio and video)"* `Desktop.getDesktop().open(aFile)` 2) See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters. 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE].

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for the suggestions.  I read a little bit about process builder and the javadoc for the Process class suggest using process builder.  I will look into what you have said and update the post with my findings.

Comment: @VGR I saw other examples of programs using the Process class do something with input and output streams.  Your comment has confirmed that it is something I will have to look into.  I'm going to update the post with what I find, but it might be a day or two.  Also it was ffplay that was hanging, but I assume it is due to my own error because it runs just fine from the terminal.